# How to create 2d array from two 1d arrays

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to ask you if there is any function in js/jquery that creates 2d array from two 1d arrays.
I know that i can do it manually like:

```
    var output = new Array(table1.length);    
    for(var i=0; i<table1.length; i++)
    {
       output[i] = new Array(2)
       output[i][0] = table1[i]
       output[i][1] = table2[i]
    }
```

But maybe there is any function which does it for me ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always write your own function, it's not that difficult. Though 1 tip/recommendation: Don't use the `Array` constructor, because as soon as you start using variables to instantiate new arrays, in a loose typed language such as JS, it might produce unexpected results.
Take this for example:

```
var nArr = new Array(3);//[undefined,undefined,undefined]
var userInput = document.getElementById('userInputTextField').value;//assume input was 3
var nArr = new Array(userInput);//['3'] <-- value of elements is string!
```

that said, here's an example function:

```
function getArray(table1, table2)
{
    var i, out = [];//literal new array
    for(i=0;i<table1.length;i++)
    {
        out.push([table1[i],table2[i]]);
    }
    return out;
}
var arr = getArray(document.getElementById('table1').rows,document.getElementById('table2').rows);
```

That should give you what you need